# When encoding a UTF-8 string with 3 character bytes how come the length only increases by 1

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So I'm trying to make sure I understand encoding correctly so I wrote a sample test:

```
public class TestEncoding {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        TestEncoding testEncoding = new TestEncoding();
        testEncoding.isLengthDifferenceBetweenUTF16UTF32();
    }

    private void isLengthDifferenceBetweenUTF16UTF32() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String eightBitString = new String("Hi how are you?ࢤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String sixteenBitString = new String("Hi how are you?ࢤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
        String thirtyTwoBitString= new String("Hi how are you?ࢤ".getBytes("UTF-32"));

        System.err.println("8 bit: " + eightBitString.length());
        System.err.println("16 bit: " + sixteenBitString.length());
        System.err.println("32 bit: " + thirtyTwoBitString.length());
    }
}
```

And then for output I get:

```
8 bit: 16
16 bit: 32
32 bit: 64
```

My question is why didn't the special character `ࢤ` on the end of `Hi how are you?`, make it 15, for the `Hi how are you?` + 3 for the special character, giving me a total of 18.

Comment: Please add the proper programming language tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String eightBitString = new String("Hi how are you?ࢤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String sixteenBitString = new String("Hi how are you?ࢤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
String thirtyTwoBitString= new String("Hi how are you?ࢤ".getBytes("UTF-32"));
```

These lines are taking a string, converting them to bytes in the specified charset, and then converting them back to a string in the JVM's default charset.

It depends on what that default is, but it is possible that the byte sequences are not valid in the default charset. In that case, the strings will contain placeholder chars for the invalid sequences. They look like `�` in the resulting string, which is a single char.

For example, if the default charset is UTF-8, these 3 strings are:

```
Hi how are you?ࢤ
Hi how are you?�
Hi how are you?�
```

If you want to compare the lengths of the byte representations in those charsets, don't convert back to strings:

```
byte[] eightBit = "Hi how are you?ࢤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(eightBit.length);
```

etc.